# How to make a Mac non-App Store distribution target for my App Store application?

Tags: macos, app-store, distribution

Much to my dismay, I just learned that there is no volume purchase program for Mac App Store. As I have promised a client a volume rebate, I need to find another way to provide them with an installer, and then bill them directly.

What is the easiest way to create an XCode target that will make a disk image + installer from the current target that is aimed at App Store distribution?

Best regards,
  Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XCode 4:
If you've made a build, your app will be in the left pane of the navigator under "Products". The reason you've overlooked this so far would be that 1) you don't need to go here ever if you just build stuff for the App Store and 2) there's a god-awfull mess of stuff in that pane that you rarely or never use.

DRM for the App Store is not involved per se, but the app is signed when sent to the app store. This either has no bearing on how the product works, or happens to a copy elsewhere as part of the distribution process. In any event, it does not appear to matter.

You do have to look out if you have implemented any way to verify the App Store receipt. This code will of course fail, as there will be no receipt.

Finally, you may want to package the app nicely in a disk image.

Make a folder with a relevant name (such as nameofapp). Copy the app to the folder (right-click the app in products, choose Show in finder). Open Disk tool. Say File -> new -> Image from folder. Make a few choices, probably "Compressed image". Wait a few moments, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Mac applications don't typically contain installers. You would just create a .app bundle with XCode, and then use Disk Utility to compress it into a DMG.

Comment: OK. How do I go about that, and how do I ensure that it is not somehow encrusted with DRM that will cause trouble for my clients?

Comment: I would think that because 1) the target is set up for App Store distribution, and so has several "sign with" such and such a key settings and 2) like many App Store apps has a slip of code in it that finds and validates an App Store receipt. Mostly I - quite frankly - don't fully understand the App Store distribution mechanism, and I have no experience with the non-App Store ways of packaging and distributing apps.